# I need show posts by customer (Shortcode)

Tags: posts, shortcode, metabox

I have customers in one new custom post type. And in my posts is created one metabox with all customers (select option). Only need compare, what option select user and show all post by this customer with one shortcode.

Example: `[news by="newcustomer"]`

[image: metabox]

Answer (score 0):

First get all data using

```
 $all_posts = get_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'user_name_key' ,'meta_value'=>'your selected name from widget') );                                                                  
 foreach($all_posts as $post ){
      //add data whatever you want to display on website widget
 }
```